# how to fix jslint The '&&' subexpression should be wrapped in parens error

Tags: javascript, jslint

I put everything in parentheses but code below still throws error in jslint:

```
Problem at line 5 character 104: The '&&' subexpression should be wrapped in parens.

if ((typeof (c1) === 'string') && (typeof (c2) === 'string') && (c1 !== n...
```

How to fix ?

```
"use strict";

function t() {
    var c1, c2;
    if (((typeof (c1)) === 'string') && ((typeof (c2)) === 'string') && (c1 !== null) && (c2 !== null) && ((c1.trim()) === '') || ((c2.trim()) !== '')) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try...wrapping the '&&'-subexpression in parens?

Comment: Not an answer, but you might put the tests for null before the tests for typeof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's complaining about the form `if(a && b && c || d)` because (I suppose) it's not immediately obvious whether `&&` or `||` will take precedence.  Fix it to look like `if(a && b && (c || d))` and it will stop complaining.

Comment: +1 for explaining it, but you ought to give the resulting boolean.  Since you didn't I provided an answer with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it wants this:

```
    if (((typeof (c1) === 'string') && (typeof (c2) === 'string') && (c1 !== null) && (c2 !== null)) && ((c1.trim()) === '') || ((c2.trim()) !== '')) {
```

wrap the 4 anded expressions on the left of the && at 100.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain **you want the following**:

```
function t() {
    var c1, c2;
    if (typeof c1 === 'string' && typeof c2 === 'string' && c1 !== null && c2 !== null && (c1.trim() === '' || c2.trim() !== '')) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Not everyone knows the precedence for boolean logic, so they want you to wrap the `c1.trim() || c2.trim()` statements in parenthesis so it's clear how they get operated.

*As a side note, I think it's ridiculous that jslint wants spaces between my operators and my operands.  I think it's much more clear when there is NOT a space.*