# JSLint error The '&&' subexpression should be wrapped in parens ? OR with IF conditions error

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, syntax, jslint

JSLint gives me the following error :

> The '&&' subexpression should be wrapped in parens.

Here is the line which causes problem:

```
if (anchorLink === 'page1' || anchorLink === 'page2' || anchorLink === 'page3' && (!$('#myDiv').hasClass('boom'))) { /* stuff */ }
```

I'm sorry for asking this because a very similar, almost identical question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570868/how-to-fix-jslint-the-subexpression-should-be-wrapped-in-parens-error), but I've tryed different ways of wrapping that && condition , I can't make it work. Any help for the correct syntax would be really appreciated.

Comment: @mlclm - See [this article](http://jslinterrors.com/the-subexpression-should-be-wrapped-in-parens) for an explanation of the error. That site attempts to give explanations and solutions for all of the JSLint error messages.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link! very useful, bookmarked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is, you are currently reliying on operator precedence.
Basically you have an implicit parenthesization:

```
anchorLink === 'page1' || anchorLink === 'page2' || (anchorLink === 'page3' && !$('#myDiv').hasClass('boom'))
```

which might or might not be what you want.

For example, you might mean this instead:

```
(anchorLink === 'page1' || anchorLink === 'page2' || anchorLink === 'page3') && !$('#myDiv').hasClass('boom')
```

To avoid ambiguity, JSLint is suggesting to put explicit parenthesis in your condition.

Comment: Thank you for showing me and explaining the solution . I'm new to jQuery so I'm slowly learning.

Comment: No problem, we've all been there once! :D 
Careful though: this is something valid across JavaScript, not just jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Put parentheses around all the `anchorLink` conditions if they're supposed to be independent of the `hasClass` condition.

```
if ((anchorLink === 'page1' || anchorLink === 'page2' || anchorLink === 'page3')
    && (!$('#myDiv').hasClass('boom'))) { /* stuff */ }
```

If you only want the `hasClass` condition to be combined with `page3`, then it should be:

```
if (anchorLink === 'page1' || anchorLink === 'page2' ||
    (anchorLink === 'page3' && (!$('#myDiv').hasClass('boom')))) { /* stuff */ }
```

The second version is the interpretation you'll get if you leave out the parentheses, because `&&` has higher precedence than `||`. This is a common mistake (the first meaning is more likely to be what you intended), which is the reason why JSLint warns about it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation...makes sense. I'm new to jQuery to learning alot of usefull stuff slowly.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery, it's not even specific to Javascript. It's the same issue in most programming languages, like C and PHP.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you need to also wrap the condition before the `&&` to disambiguate the expression:

```
if ((anchorLink === 'page1' || anchorLink === 'page2' || anchorLink === 'page3') && (!$('#myDiv').hasClass('boom'))) { /* stuff */ }
```

Comment: +1, but the parens around `!$('#myDiv').hasClass('boom')` are completely pointless.

Comment: Nice one, thanks a lot... I hadn't tryed that. Thanks for your help @fiddler, really appreciated. It works.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder No need to downvote my question... ? the f ?

Comment: @mlclm: People downvote, and people comment. They're frequently not the same people. If you assume you know who downvoted a question/answer, you'll be wrong much more often than right.

Comment: Yea you are right, I don't know who downvoted, sorry for pointing my finger at you so quickly (because the downvote happened at the same time you answered my problem), I was wrong . I wasn't expecting any downvotes because there's no reason for that in my question. Anyways, I guess there will always be idiots out there to mess around for "fun". But thanks again for your help about my js problem, I really appreciated that, that's what is important. Furthermore I think my question will help other users to understand that JSLiint error and how to resolve it in the future, so that's a good thing.